# grid system in bootstrap

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a scenario where I need the following view in large resolution: [image]

and the following in small and medium resolution: [image]

I have tried:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="img-blocks small-image col-lg-2 clearfix">
            <ul class="list-style">
                <li ng-repeat="img in productImgSrc track by $index">
                    <img ng-src={{img}} alt="...">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="img-blocks zoomed-image col-lg-10 clearfix">
            <img ng-src={{productImgSrc[0]}}  alt="...">
        </div>
    </div>
```

But it's not able to make generate the view for the smaller resolution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you probably need media queries for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **CSS Flexbox**. And use media queries to reverse the order on different screen sizes.

In my example,

- Small: `max-width: 991px (0px - 991px)`
- Large: `min-width: 992px (992px > infinite)`

Have a look at my snippet below (*For large screens use **Full Screen** mode*):

```css
.main-block {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.list-style {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.list-style li {
  padding: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

/* For Small Screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .main-block {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }

  .list-style {
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .list-style li {
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row main-block">
    <div class="img-blocks small-image col-lg-2 clearfix">
        <ul class="list-style">
            <li>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40" alt="...">
            </li>
          <li>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40" alt="...">
            </li>
          <li>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40" alt="...">
            </li>
          <li>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40" alt="...">
            </li>
          <li>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40" alt="...">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="img-blocks zoomed-image col-lg-10 clearfix">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300"  alt="...">
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!